# D3 - loading data with no header

Tags: d3.js, header, load

I'm just getting started with D3 and right out of the gate I can't get started.  I am sure the solution is simple, I just can't find it or understand the answer.

I am trying to load data in a text file data.txt,  but the data does not have any headers;  three columns, tab delimited.

```
06/20/2014 13:00    3666    -134    
06/20/2014 13:10    3744    65    
06/20/2014 13:20    3778    2    
06/20/2014 13:30    3804    2    
06/20/2014 13:40    3865    -1    
06/20/2014 13:50    3924    2    
06/20/2014 14:00    3939    -173    
06/20/2014 14:10    3966    -121    
06/20/2014 14:20    3989    -108    
06/20/2014 14:30    4000    -117    
06/20/2014 14:40    3729    -109    
06/20/2014 14:50    4022    -94    
06/20/2014 15:00    3794    -204    
06/20/2014 15:10    3629    53    
06/20/2014 15:20    3572    179    
06/20/2014 15:30    3847    166
```

I want to draw a line with the second column of data.

I also have a larger file, where I want to draw a line from a row of data 168 columns long:

```
OFFICIAL,2014-06-30 22:00:00,BAW,361,459,536,591,677,720,725,707,611,524,446,382,339,289,238,183,170,227,393,....
```

I know how to do the drawing stuff from my experience with Processing, but I just can't figure out how to get the column of data and the row of data identified in the D3 code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've discovered, the d3 file-parsing functions expect data to be in a standard table format with column headers on the first row.

However, there are variations on the same methods that give you greater control ([see the d3 API wiki for more](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV)).  For your no-header data table, the approach is:

- Use `d3.text(filename, function(error, textString) )` to read the entire file without parsing it.
- In your callback function, use `d3.tsv.parseRows(textString)` to generate your data array without assigning column headers.

  ```
  var data = d3.tsv.parseRows(textString)
  ```

  Each data value will then consist of a numbered array, so that you would access the date as `d[0]`, the time as `d[1]`, and so on.
- Alternately, you can create your own header row as a string of tab-separated labels and concatenate it to the beginning of the text string from the data file, and use a one of the `parse` methods.

  ```
  var headers = ["date","time","data1","data2"].join("\t");
  var data = d3.tsv.parse(headers + textString)
  ```

In either case, the end result will be an array of data points, each of which contain multiple values.  You calculate the path data by passing this array to a `d3.svg.line()` function after setting the appropriate accessor functions (either using array notation or object name notation, depending on whether you added a header).  There are plenty of examples of line graphs in the [tutorials section of the wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials).

For your data file that is all as a single row in one CSV file, you'll want to use the `parseRows` approach described above.  This will return a one-element data array (representing your one row), but that element will be the array of data that you're really interested in.  You'll have to slice off the initial values to just get the list of numbers:

```
    var rowData = d3.tsv.parseRows(textString)[0];
    var data = rowData.slice(3);
```